# What language construct is " {rank=same; A B C} " in graphviz

Tags: syntax, graphviz, dot

In graphviz/dot, I can place nodes on the same rank with `{rank=same; ND1 ND2 ND3}`.

Looking at the [dot language](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language), I conclude that `{...}` is part of the *subgraph statement*.

If this is the case, I don't understand why I need a subgraph to rank nodes. I assume this is because I don't have a correct mental image of what constitutes a subgraph in graphviz.

So, my question is: what is a subgraph in graphviz exactly and why do I have to start a subgraph to rank nodes that don't have anything to do with this subgraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you cite:

> In the second role, a subgraph can provide a context for setting attributes. For example, a subgraph could specify that blue is the default color for all nodes defined in it. In the context of graph drawing, a more interesting example is:

```
subgraph { 
rank = same; A; B; C; 
}
```

> This (anonymous) subgraph specifies that the nodes A, B and C should all be placed on the same rank if drawn using dot.

This use of subgraphs to set rank of nodes is exactly the sort of context to which the documentation is referring (explicitly in this case).  The *syntax* supports a special *contextual* meaning in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I had read the sentence you quoted, but apparently didn't not really digest it.